# Using some in-browser OpenStreetMap (or other) API, can I get a list of exits from the street I'm currently on, to other streets?

Tags: openstreetmap

Ideally I would send a lat/lng/direction/accuracy, and receive a list with info like:

- 50m ahead, you could turn 90 degrees right onto STREET_ID
- 50m ahead, you could turn 45 degrees left onto STREET_ID

etc

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/49730/using-some-in-browser-osm-or-other-api-can-i-get-a-list-of-exits-from-the-street-im-on-to-other-streets

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: @Karussell I'm building a little app to help people wander towards each other without specifying a meeting place, which gives audio guidance about which turns to make to increase the likelihood of a rendezvous

Comment: Why not find the meeting place and guide them towards it? E.g. A and B, find middle X then guide A to X and B to X?

Comment: There are various routing services and/or APIs, check out http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing